# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o143.parquet

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

So I have parquet files in S3 bucket and I want to load it using pyspark in python, but I'm getting some error, here's what I have tried so far. I'm using Juputer Notebook in EMR Cluster.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("app name").config("spark.some.config.option", True).getOrCreate()

file = s3://somelocation
df = spark.read.parquet(file)
```

This is giving me following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3146/2307354378.py in <module>
----> 1 df = spark.read.parquet(file)
      2 df

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths, **options)
    456                        modifiedAfter=modifiedAfter)
    457 
--> 458         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    459 
    460     def text(self, paths, wholetext=False, lineSep=None, pathGlobFilter=None,

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.parquet.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked multiple similar post and tried everything, still nothing is working. I tried to change the `s3` path to `s3a` as mentioned in one post, then I got another error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.parquet.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2593)
    ... 25 more
```

So I also tried to download the data to my instance locally and then tried:

```
spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .appName('loss_comfal')
         .config('spark.executor.memory', '110G')
         .config('spark.driver.memory', '110G')
         .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '110G')
         .getOrCreate())
        
files = glob.glob('data/*')
df = spark.read.parquet(files)
```

which returned me another error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.parquet.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.$anonfun$newHadoopConfWithOptions$1(SessionState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.$anonfun$newHadoopConfWithOptions$1$adapted(SessionState.scala:102)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.newHadoopConfWithOptions(SessionState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.newHadoopConfiguration(DataSource.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know there are similar post solved, and I have tried all of them but none is working.

Answer (score 1):

The first error `No FileSystem for scheme "s3"` is because the file system should be `s3a` or `s3n`, not `s3`

The second error `Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found` means you missing S3 package like `org.apache.spark.hadoop-cloud_2.12`. But at least you got the file system correct.

The third error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String` means something in your dataset suppose to be String, but it's ArrayList instead and Spark cannot convert it. Maybe the file is corrupted or missing something.